# java.net.SocketException - Trying to fetch XML

Tags: java, xml, socketexception

I have a simple code that fetches a XML file from the web. More specific, a XML file with exchange rates from a norwegian bank. The problem is, it only works sometimes. Usually, it never works the first time.

After some testing, I'm pretty sure its crashes on `InputStreamReader(url.openStream())`. But as a said, not every time.

So, is it any better way to to this, and ensure that it fetches the XML file correctly

All help is appriciated.

```
public class xmlReader {

private static Properties intProps;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    intProps = new Properties();

    intProps.setProperty("SOURCEURL", "https://www.dnb.no/portalfront/datafiles/miscellaneous/csv/kursliste_ws.xml");
    intProps.setProperty("SOURCEDIR", "C:\\Users\\");
    intProps.setProperty("SOURCEFILE", "EXCHANGERATES_#YYYYMMDD#_#U#.xml");     
    fetchURL();
}


private static void fetchURL() {
    try {

        URL url = new URL(intProps.getProperty("SOURCEURL"));
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));


        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(intProps.getProperty("SOURCEDIR") + intProps.getProperty("SOURCEFILE"));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                   System.out.println("Line: " + inputLine);
          fout.write(inputLine.getBytes());                        
        }

        fout.close();

        in.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                 // writeLog("Error fetching from URL: " + e.getMessage());                                                                           
    }
```

}

> The error is as following:
>
> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset    at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.kickstart(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everytime I want do download a file, I use this code ( or derviations )

```
try {   
 URL url;
 url = new URL("http://YourWebSourceXML.xml");  


 InputStream in = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
 OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("YourDestFile.xml");
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 for (int n;(n = in.read(buffer)) != -1;
         out.write(buffer, 0, n));

 in.close();
 out.close(); }
 catch (IOException e){
 // Do something
 }
```

EDIT:

I got this working on first try:

```
 try {

    URL url = new URL("http://www.dnb.no/portalfront/datafiles/miscellaneous/csv/kursliste_ws.xml");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));


    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("x.xml");

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println("Line: " + inputLine);
      fout.write(inputLine.getBytes());                        
    }

    fout.close();

    in.close();

} catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
             // writeLog("Error fetching from URL: " + e.getMessage());                                                                           
}
```

Quick and dirty, maybe this will help.

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, but i still get the same error. On your code it crashes on:
InputStream in = url.openConnection().getInputStream();

Comment: I edited my first answer, works good at my place. Maybe you will give it a try.

Comment: Thank you very much again. Does it work every time? It works sometimes, but usally the first time i get a java.net.SocketExeption (The error i posted). Fails at InputStreamReader(url.openStream());

Comment: I tried it several times and did not get any Exceptions for now. First I thought it was a Problem with https, but it seems it runs with https also. EDIT: Finally i got the Problem using "https" instead of "http"... maybe this is your problem?

Comment: ok, thank you very much. Maybe i have a connection issue. I though it had something to do with https to. Now i am not sure what to do to :(

Comment: Maybe you should use http. I did reproduce your error 2 times using https, no Exception using http.

Comment: I tried http, and i don't get the error anymore. So strange? Anyways, thank you very much for your help!